# Google maps android app build error :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: android, google-maps, build.gradle

I am currently developing a custom themed version of google maps, and have spent the past god knows how long trying to resolve this build error. I have researched this extensively, and found nothing which seems to help solve my problem.

I have included my app/build.gradle file below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wtwelectronics.googlemapsrev2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
//         Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The 1st error line of the gradle console output is below:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
```

I am using android studio 2.3.1, with latest SDK packages etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try cleaning and building again?

Comment: Probably, `google-services.json` is missing

Comment: The build--> make project/clean project/rebuild all complete successfully, I've tried that a million and one times, the issue only arises when android studio is trying to build an apk file.

Comment: Where would I add the `google-serives.json`? I'm pretty new to android studio, so may be sounding stupid.

Comment: Try going over the Google maps Android tutorial step-by-step. It'll answer that

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in your gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
```

and look at [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/ApiDemos) example for more.

Comment: and also you have to put your JSON inside the app folder. just copy & paste it there.

Comment: Okay, tried that and got the exact same error. Busy looking into the json file stuff. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @wtw You need to replace the existing Google services line with this, not add

Comment: Still fails. The gradle sync completes fine, but as soon as I run the apk build, the dex transform process throws exceptions.